# Back from matrix form to linear form in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am learning linear algebra in SymPy. I have equations with Pauli matrices.

Let's say I have

```
sigma_0 = Matrix([[1, 0],[0, 1]])
sigma_1 = Matrix([[0, 1],[1, 0]])
sigma_2 = Matrix([[0, -I],[I, 0]])
```

Now, I want to do some basics algebra like

```
sigma_1 + 2*sigma_2
```

As a result it gives me matrix. And I want to convert it as sigma_1 + 2*sigma_2. How to convert it from matrix form to linear form?

Comment: @sagi I want it as a simplified equation more, not as a matrix form. For example I want to calculate 2*sigma_1 + sigma_2 - 5*sigma_1, where sigma_1 and sigma_2 is matrices. And it gives me a matrix as a result. What I want is a result as: -3*sigma_1 + sigma_2

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is to simplify an expression that will potentially contain any of these matrices. In fact, it has nothing to do with the matrices themselves but rather with simplifications. So what I suggest is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

def function_simplifier(x,y,z,a,b,c):
    return simplify(a*x +b*y +c*z)
```

so, for

```
2*sigma_1 + sigma_2 - 5*sigma_1
```

This would be:

```
function_simplifier(y,z,y,2,1,-5)
```

which returns:

```
-3*y + z
```

Now, if you want to calculate the result:

```
A = simplify(function_simplifier(y,z,y,2,1,-5))
f = lambdify((x,y,z),A)

f(sigma_0,sigma_1,sigma_2)
```

which will return the matrix

```
Matrix([[0, -3 - I], [-3 + I, 0]])
```

Comment: I know, I wrote my question inappropriate. Better example is, that I want to calculate: 2*sigma_1 + sigma_2 - 5*sigma_1. As a result I get matrix. I would like it to give me result like: -3*sigma_1 + sigma_2.

Comment: Now, I see. Going to look into that

Comment: Updated my answer with what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MatrixSymbols and then substitute in the matrices when you want to see the actual value:

```
>>> from sympy import Matrix, MatrixSymbol
>>> sigma_0 = Matrix([[1, 0],[0, 1]])
>>> sigma_1 = Matrix([[0, 1],[1, 0]])
>>> sigma_2 = Matrix([[0, -I],[I, 0]])
>>> a,b,c = [MatrixSymbol(i,2,2) for i in 'ABC']
>>> 2*a+b-3*a
-A + B
>>> _.subs({a: sigma_0, b:sigma_1})
Matrix([
[0, 1],
[1, 0]]) - Matrix([
[1, 0],
[0, 1]])
>>> _.doit()  # or _.subs(...).doit(), too
Matrix([
[-1,  1],
[ 1, -1]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to the inverse operation? I mean, let's say, we have our sigma matrices, we do some calculation in Matrix Form and we have our final result in matrix form. Is it possible to decompose this matrix form in sigma basis?

Comment: That's just a system of linear equations, right? `solve(x*sigma_0 + y*sigma_1 - result) -> {x: ca, y: cb} so result = ca*a + cb*b`